# Change detection seems to not work in a dynamically instantiated component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

(Working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmdbxw))

I made a very simple component which displays a message for 3s then a "Done" message :

**footer.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  waiting = true;

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.waiting = false, 3000);
  }

}
```

**footer.component.html**

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div *ngIf="waiting">Waiting 3s</div>
  <div *ngIf="!waiting">Done !</div>
</div>
```

This component works like a charm when added to a template with `app-footer`.

However, when instantiated dynamically with a Material's `BottomSheet`, the change detection does not happen. The variable `waiting` has the right value but the displayed text is wrong. I have to manually call the `ChangeDetectorRef`.

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private _bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet) {}

showBottomSheet() {
  this._bottomSheet.open(FooterComponent);
}
```

After looking on StackOverflow, I learnt that change detection behaves differently with dynamically instantiated components but it seems that the only change is with `@Input()` variables. Is it the expected behavior ? Is it a bug from Material's `BottomSheet`?

Comment: Maybe this thread is going to answer your question https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12931

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Material BottomSheet wraps your component with 'mat-bottom-sheet-container' which sets ChangeDetection to OnPush so your FooterComponent inherits it. You have to manually trigger change detection by injecting ChangeDetectorRef and calling 'markForCheck' method ;)

Comment: Life saving answer. This applies to the mat-right-sheet (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-right-sheet) as well.